# Return json object from bind_result

Tags: php

I have simple PHP script that returns me user object, and it looks like this

```
<?php
require_once '../dbConnect.php';
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION["id"])) {
    http_response_code(401);
    return;
}

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, firstName, lastName, email FROM users WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION["id"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $firstName, $lastName, $email);
    $stmt->fetch();

    $member['id'] = $id;
    $member['firstName'] = $firstName;
    $member['lastName'] = $lastName;
    $member['email'] = $email;

    echo json_encode($member);

    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();;

?>
```

My question: Is there a better way to return json object than this, where i need to create object with every property, is there something more "automatic" for this kind of stuff ?

```
$member['id'] = $id;
$member['firstName'] = $firstName;
$member['lastName'] = $lastName;
$member['email'] = $email;
echo json_encode($member);
```

I'm asking this because i had this same script written like this, but i change it to prepared statement because of performance and security

```
<?php
require_once '../dbConnect.php';
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION["id"])) {
    http_response_code(401);
    return;
}

$memberId = $_SESSION["id"];
$query="SELECT id, firstName, lastName, email FROM users WHERE id='$memberId'";

$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
$member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo json_encode($member);

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

and i used simply

```
$member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo json_encode($member);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the MYSQLND driver, you can use `fetch_assoc()` with a prepared statement.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, firstName, lastName, email FROM users WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION["id"]);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$member = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

If not, you can refer to the array elements directly in `bind_result()`, instead of using separate variables.

```
$member = array();
$stmt->bind_result($member['id'], $member['firstName'], $member['lastName'], $member['email']);
```

Comment: I dont have MYSQLND driver, also i edited my question can you see it now

Comment: I see it, it doesn't change my answer. You can't use `fetch_assoc()` with a prepared statement unless you have the MYSQLND driver.

Comment: So let me verify with you, if i install mysqlnd i can simply use after $stmt-fetch();  $member = $stmt->fetch_assoc();, also can you tell me is my new script better than my old where i did not use prepared statement

Comment: If you install MYSQLND, you use `$stmt->fetch_assoc()` INSTEAD of `$stmt->bind_result()` and `$stmt->fetch()`.

Comment: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc()  i get that and i did this 

 `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, firstName, lastName, email FROM users WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION["id"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetch_assoc($id, $firstName, $lastName, $email);
    
    echo json_encode($stmt);`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a step. You have to call `$stmt->get_result()`, that returns a result object that you can call `fetch_assoc()` on.

Comment: It's working good thank you, just one more question if i'm expecting array would i do same thing with fetch_assoc() or with array i use something else ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can call `fetch_assoc()` in a loop, to get each of the rows, and push each row onto an array.